# Does the AMPscript call for ReplaceList() work when using declared variables?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

Trying to replace values in a pipe-delimited string that is pulled from another snippet of AMPscript so that I can place the replaced data into a URL string.

At a high-level I want to take this (for example):   Home|Away|Away|Home|Tomorrow|Today
and replace these with a numeric value so that it becomes:  1|2|2|1|3|4

I tried doing just this with the following script:

%%[
Set @somevariable == 
ReplaceList(@string, "Home", "1")
ReplaceList(@string, "Away", "2")
ReplaceList(@string, "Tomorrow", "3")
ReplaceList(@string, "Today", "4")
]%%

This would then go into a URL, for example:  http://www.shop.ca?when=%%=@somevariable=%%
to become:   http://www.shop.ca?when=1|2|2|1|3|4

However, when I try this it simply won't work.  I pared back my call just to try to replace the string, and got that to work fine but not with a variable - it was with a static value.

That all said, is it possible to complete a ReplaceList in AMPscript when the string is another variable?

Help!

Comment: Can you post the whole AMPscript code block?

Comment: You're not using the == in you're code right? You need to use the single = to set a variable; the == would ensure things would never work right.

Comment: SET @seeds = Lookup("Daily-Categories","Product Categories Viewed - Top","EmailAddress",emailaddr)

ReplaceList(@seeds, "Electronics", "10108")
ReplaceList(@seeds, "House & Home", "10111")
ReplaceList(@seeds, "Clothing", "10106")
ReplaceList(@seeds, "Computers", "10053")
ReplaceList(@seeds, "Shoes", "10117")
ReplaceList(@seeds, "Toys & Hobbies", "10121")
ReplaceList(@seeds, "Arts & Crafts", "10101")
ReplaceList(@seeds, "Office Supplies", "10126")
ReplaceList(@seeds, "Software", "10118")
ReplaceList(@seeds, "Games & Puzzles", "10109")